# How to compute the gradient of $f(x,y)=Y^T(x,y)A(x,y)Y(x,y)$ where $A=A^T$?

Tags: calculus, linear-algebra, optimization

I need to find a minimum for

$f(x,y)=Y^T(x,y)A(x,y)Y(x,y)$

where $A(x,y)$ is a symmetric matrix and $Y(x,y)$ is a vector whose components are functions of $x$ and $y$.

Eg in $\mathbb{R}^2$:

$$Y(x,y) = \left(\begin{array}{c}{g(x,y) \\ h(x,y)}\end{array}\right)$$

where $g,h:\mathbb{R}^2\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$. Similarly for $A(x,y)$

This is in $\mathbb{R}$ (but It would also be interesting to consider the complex case)

How can I find a matricial expression for the gradient of $f(x,y)$?

Comment: Can you explain the notation you're using? i.e. what is $Y(x,y)$ ? is it the vector $Y$ dotted with the vector $(x,y)$? or is the vector $Y$ parameterized by $x$ and $y$?

Comment: It's the $Y$ parametrized by $x$ and $y$.

Comment: Hint: use the product rule.

Answer (score 0):

So you want to find the derivative of the quadratic form $f(x,y)=(x,y)^{T}A(x,y)$ $$f(x,y) = (x,y)^{T}\cdot\left(x\left(\begin{array}{c} a_{1,1}\\
a_{2,1}
\end{array}\right)+y\left(\begin{array}{c}
a_{2,1}\\
a_{2,2}
\end{array}\right)\right)$$
$$= (x,y)^{T}\cdot\left(\begin{array}{c}
xa_{1,1}+ya_{1,2}\\
xa_{2,1}+ya_{2,2}
\end{array}\right)$$
    $$= x\left(xa_{1,1}+ya_{1,2}\right)+y\left(xa_{2,1}+ya_{2,2}\right)$$
$$=x^{2}a_{1,1}+2xy\cdot a_{1,2}+y^{2}a_{2,2}$$

where we used the fact that $A$ is symmetric for the last equality.

so, you can take the partial derivative of $f(x,y)=x^{2}a_{1,1}+2xy\cdot a_{1,2}+y^{2}a_{2,2}$ with respect to $x$ and $y$ to get $\nabla f =2\cdot A(x,y)$. I'll leave those details for you to fill in.

Comment: Sorry what I meant by $Y(x,y)$ is that $Y$'s components are functions of $x$ and $y$. So, in your answer I would need to replace $(x,y)$ by $(g(x,y),h(x,y))$ where $g,h:\mathbb{R}^2\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$